# Changing icon colors and based on which item is selected. working snippet included

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm hoping someone can help me finish up my code.

I'm basically trying to have icons change when certain item is clicked. Then when the icon is clicked, it animates up and down at the same time changing icon images.

I'm ALMOST there. You'll notice an issue when you click through the items, then when you reach item 3, the toggle automatically opens and closes.

Please see my snippet and see if you guys can help me tighten this thing up.

```js
//CHANGE COLOR

function changeColor1() {
  $('.jumbotron').css('background-color', '#6aabcb');
  $('.topBar').css('background-color', '#bdd2f1');
  $('.topBarInner').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)');
}

function changeColor2() {
  $('.jumbotron').css('background-color', '#e4b028');
  $('.topBar').css('background-color', '#ffce4e');
  $('.topBarInner').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png) ');
}

function changeColor3() {
  $('.jumbotron').css('background-color', '#6990f4');
  $('.topBar').css('background-color', '#4e7fff');
  $('.topBarInner').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-darkblue.png)');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.navLink').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    switch (id) {
      case 'nav1':
        $(".topBarInner").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
            $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({
              marginTop: "0px"
            }, 200);
            $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200);
            $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)");
          } else {
            $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({
              marginTop: "160px"
            }, 200);
            $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200);
            $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png)");
          }

          $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
          return false;

        });
        break;
      case 'nav2':
        $(".topBarInner").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")) {
            $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({
              marginTop: "0px"
            }, 200);
            $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200);
            $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png)");
          } else {
            $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({
              marginTop: "160px"
            }, 200);
            $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200);
            $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png)");
          }

          $(this).toggleClass("clickedYellow");
          return false;

        });
        break;
      case 'nav3':
        $(".topBarInner").click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")) {
            $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({
              marginTop: "0px"
            }, 200);
            $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200);
            $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-darkblue.png)");
          } else {
            $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({
              marginTop: "160px"
            }, 200);
            $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200);
            $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png)");
          }

          $(this).toggleClass("clickedBlue");
          return false;

        });
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.headerRow {
  padding: 52px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 175px 0 0px 0;
  background-color: #6aabcb;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.topBar {
  height: 11px;
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #bdd2f1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.topBarInner {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clicked {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png);
}

.clickedYellow {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png);
}

.clickedBlue {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row headerRow">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/logo.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron"></div>

<div id="contentContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="topBar">
        <div class="topBarInner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeColor1()" id="nav1" class="navLink">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeColor2()" id="nav2" class="navLink">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="changeColor3()" id="nav3" class="navLink">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/container-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think using `$(".topBarInner").off("click")` just before your switch in your jquery will solve alot of problems

Comment: *"You'll notice an issue when you click through the items, then when you reach item 3, the toggle automatically opens and closes"* - I'm not seeing that problem.. How do you mean?

Comment: @KobyDouek I think he refers to the click function on the plus icon, it opens and close lots of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there are two problems.

1. You need to unbind the click event
2. In case "nav3", you are checking if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")). It should be if ($(this).hasClass("clickedBlue")).
3. Move out the logic to attach the click event outside of switch statement.

**Complete code:**

```js
function changeColor1() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#6aabcb');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#bdd2f1');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)');
}

function changeColor2() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#e4b028');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#ffce4e');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png) ');
}
    
function changeColor3() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#6990f4');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#4e7fff');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-darkblue.png)');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 var id = 'nav1';
    $('.navLink').on('click', function () {
  id = this.id;
   });
  $(".topBarInner").unbind('click');
  $(".topBarInner").click( function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   switch(id) {
  case 'nav1':
    if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
     $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
     $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
     $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)");
    } else {
     $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
     $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
     $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png)");
    } 

    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    break;
  case 'nav2':
    if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")) {
     $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
     $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
     $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png)");
    } else {
     $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
     $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
     $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png)");
    } 

    $(this).toggleClass("clickedYellow");

    break;
  case 'nav3':
    if ($(this).hasClass("clickedBlue")) {
     $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
     $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
     $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-darkblue.png)");
    } else {
     $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
     $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
     $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png)");
    } 

    $(this).toggleClass("clickedBlue");
    break;
    
   }
  });
});
```

```css
.headerRow{
 padding:52px 0;
    position: relative;
 } 
    
.jumbotron {
 margin-top:-10px;
 padding:175px 0 0px 0;
 background-color:#6aabcb;
 color: white;
 position:relative;
 }
    
.topBar{
 height:11px;
 width:98%;
 background-color:#bdd2f1;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:20px;
 }
 
.topBarInner{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 height:28px;
 width:28px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
    
.clicked{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png);
 }
    
.clickedYellow{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png);
 }
    
.clickedBlue{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row headerRow">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/logo.jpg"/></a> 
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="jumbotron"></div>

<div id="contentContainer">   
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="topBar"><div class="topBarInner"></div></div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor1()" id="nav1" class="navLink">Item 1</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor2()" id="nav2" class="navLink">Item 2</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor3()" id="nav3" class="navLink">Item 3</a></li>    
            </ul>     
       </div>
    </div> 
</div><!--/container-->
```

Comment: This is perfect! 
ONE more thing: the plus icon currently does not work until one of the list item has been clicked. 
How can I get the plus icon to animate on click before any list item has been clicked?

Comment: Since $(".topBarInner").click( function(event) event is attached inside $('.navLink') click event, it will not fire until first navlink is clicked. So move $(".topBarInner").click( function(event)  directly in $(document).ready. Please have a look I just added and let me know if you have any question.

Comment: I could not get this to work. If I move $(".topBarInner").click( function(event) directly in $(document).ready, it won't fire when navlink is clicked. I also tried naming the $(".topBarInner").click( function(event) and calling it directly under $(document).ready but that didn't work either.

Comment: You need to change navLink click as below.Did you change it? 
 var id = 'nav1'; 
$('.navLink').on('click', function () 
{ 
 id = this.id; 
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unbind()` or `off()` for this. Check updated snippet below:

```js
//CHANGE COLOR
        
function changeColor1() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#6aabcb');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#bdd2f1');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)');
}

function changeColor2() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#e4b028');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#ffce4e');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png) ');
}
    
function changeColor3() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#6990f4');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#4e7fff');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-darkblue.png)');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navLink').on('click', function () {
      var id = this.id;
      switch(id) {
        case 'nav1':
           $(".topBarInner").unbind("click");
           $(".topBarInner").click( function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
                    $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
                    $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
                    $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)");
                } else {
                    $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
                    $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
                    $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png)");
                } 

                $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
                return false;

            });
          break;
        case 'nav2':
              $(".topBarInner").unbind("click");
              $(".topBarInner").click( function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")) {
                        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
                        $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
                        $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png)");
                    } else {
                        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
                        $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
                        $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png)");
                    } 

                    $(this).toggleClass("clickedYellow");
                    return false;

                });
          break;
        case 'nav3':
              $(".topBarInner").unbind("click");
              $(".topBarInner").click( function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")) {
                        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
                        $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
                        $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-darkblue.png)");
                    } else {
                        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
                        $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
                        $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png)");
                    } 

                    $(this).toggleClass("clickedBlue");
                    return false;

                });
          break;
      }
    }); 
});
```

```css
.headerRow{
 padding:52px 0;
    position: relative;
 } 
    
.jumbotron {
 margin-top:-10px;
 padding:175px 0 0px 0;
 background-color:#6aabcb;
 color: white;
 position:relative;
 }
    
.topBar{
 height:11px;
 width:98%;
 background-color:#bdd2f1;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:20px;
 }
 
.topBarInner{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 height:28px;
 width:28px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
    
.clicked{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png);
 }
    
.clickedYellow{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png);
 }
    
.clickedBlue{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row headerRow">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/logo.jpg"/></a> 
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="jumbotron"></div>

<div id="contentContainer">   
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="topBar"><div class="topBarInner"></div></div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor1()" id="nav1" class="navLink">Item 1</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor2()" id="nav2" class="navLink">Item 2</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor3()" id="nav3" class="navLink">Item 3</a></li>    
            </ul>     
       </div>
    </div> 
</div><!--/container-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looked like you had 2 problems in your code,

First you had a `if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")) {` in your last `case`, I believe it should be `clickedBlue`

Second Add `$(".topBarInner").off("click")` just before the start of your `switch`. Because that each time you click on a `nav` item, you generate a new click event for `topBarInner`.

```js
//CHANGE COLOR
        
function changeColor1() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#6aabcb');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#bdd2f1');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)');
}

function changeColor2() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#e4b028');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#ffce4e');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png) ');
}
    
function changeColor3() {
    $('.jumbotron').css('background-color','#6990f4');
    $('.topBar').css('background-color','#4e7fff');
    $('.topBarInner').css('background-image','url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-darkblue.png)');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.navLink').on('click', function () {
      var id = this.id;
      $(".topBarInner").off("click")
      switch(id) {
        case 'nav1':
           $(".topBarInner").click( function(event){
                event.preventDefault();

                if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
                    $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
                    $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
                    $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png)");
                } else {
                    $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
                    $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
                    $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png)");
                } 

                $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
                return false;

            });
          break;
        case 'nav2':
              $(".topBarInner").click( function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")) {
                        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
                        $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
                        $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-yellow.png)");
                    } else {
                        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
                        $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
                        $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png)");
                    } 

                    $(this).toggleClass("clickedYellow");
                    return false;

                });
          break;
        case 'nav3':
              $(".topBarInner").click( function(event){
                    event.preventDefault();

                    if ($(this).hasClass("clickedBlue")) {
                        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"0px"}, 200); 
                        $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200); 
                        $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up-darkblue.png)");
                    } else {
                        $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({marginTop:"160px"}, 200);
                        $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200); 
                        $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png)");
                    } 

                    $(this).toggleClass("clickedBlue");
                    return false;

                });
          break;
      }
    }); 
});
```

```css
.headerRow{
 padding:52px 0;
    position: relative;
 } 
    
.jumbotron {
 margin-top:-10px;
 padding:175px 0 0px 0;
 background-color:#6aabcb;
 color: white;
 position:relative;
 }
    
.topBar{
 height:11px;
 width:98%;
 background-color:#bdd2f1;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:20px;
 }
 
.topBarInner{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:contain;
 height:28px;
 width:28px;
 margin:0 auto;
 }
    
.clicked{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png);
 }
    
.clickedYellow{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png);
 }
    
.clickedBlue{
 background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png);
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row headerRow">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/logo.jpg"/></a> 
    </div>  
</div>

<div class="jumbotron"></div>

<div id="contentContainer">   
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="topBar"><div class="topBarInner"></div></div>  
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">
            <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor1()" id="nav1" class="navLink">Item 1</a></li>   
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor2()" id="nav2" class="navLink">Item 2</a></li>    
                <li><a href="#" onclick="changeColor3()" id="nav3" class="navLink">Item 3</a></li>    
            </ul>     
       </div>
    </div> 
</div><!--/container-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eric your code can be short by using the below points

1. If you are already using jQuery then no need to call functions onclick of anchors.
2. Its not a good practice to bind `click` event every time when a link is clicked.
3. Try to use static variables for images URLs having same domain.
4. Try to remove the redundant code with a single `if-else` block.

```js
//CHANGE COLOR
$(document).ready(function() {
  var burl = "url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/",
  nav=[{jb:'#6aabcb',tb:'#bdd2f1',i:'arrow-up'},
        {jb:'#e4b028',tb:'#ffce4e',i:'arrow-up-yellow'},
        {jb:'#6990f4',tb:'#4e7fff',i:'arrow-up-darkblue'}];
  $('.navLink').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ind = parseInt(this.id.replace('nav',''))-1;
    $('.navLink.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if(nav[ind] && nav[ind].hasOwnProperty('jb')){
      $('.jumbotron').css('background-color', nav[ind].jb);
      $('.topBar').css('background-color', nav[ind].tb);
      $('.topBarInner').css('background-image',burl+nav[ind].i+'.png)');
    }
  });

  $(".topBarInner").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("clicked") || $(this).hasClass("clickedYellow") || $(this).hasClass("clickedBlue")) {
      $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({
        marginTop: "0px"
      }, 200);
      $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").show(200);
    } else {
      $("#contentContainer").stop().animate({
        marginTop: "160px"
      }, 200);
      $(".jumbotron, .headerRow").hide(200);
    }
    var uri = '';
    if ($('#nav1').hasClass('active')) {
      if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        uri = burl + "arrow-up.png)";
      } else {
        uri = burl + "arrow-down.png)";
      }
      $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    } else if ($('#nav2').hasClass('active')) {
      if ($(this).hasClass("clickedYellow")) {
        uri = burl + "arrow-up-yellow.png)";
      } else {
        uri = burl + "arrow-down-yellow.png)";
      }
      $(this).toggleClass("clickedYellow");
    } else if ($('#nav3').hasClass('active')) {
      if ($(this).hasClass("clickedBlue")) {
        uri = burl + "arrow-up-darkblue.png)";
      } else {
        uri = burl + "arrow-down-darkblue.png)";
      }
      $(this).toggleClass("clickedBlue");
    }
    uri && $(".topBarInner").css("background-image", uri);
  });
});
```

```css
.headerRow {
  padding: 52px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.jumbotron {
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding: 175px 0 0px 0;
  background-color: #6aabcb;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.topBar {
  height: 11px;
  width: 98%;
  background-color: #bdd2f1;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.topBarInner {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-up.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clicked {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down.png);
}

.clickedYellow {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-yellow.png);
}

.clickedBlue {
  background-image: url(http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/arrow-down-darkblue.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row headerRow">
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.ericnguyen23.com/images/host/logo.jpg" /></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron"></div>

<div id="contentContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="topBar">
        <div class="topBarInner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" id="nav1" class="navLink active">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" id="nav2" class="navLink">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" id="nav3" class="navLink">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/container-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Note: Above code can be short if we use ternary operator instead of single statement `if-else` blocks.*